# Internet Explorer - iframe api not working

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using iframe api (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

I want to be able to pause/play and mute/unmute video through iframe api.

I've created a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ke73v0ov/

```html
<iframe id="bg" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/o3z6h0EaIN0?&version=3&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&autohide=1&controls=0&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    
    
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('bg', {
            events: {
                'onReady': function (event) {
                    event.target.setVolume(50);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
    
    function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:pauseVideo()">Pause</a>
<a href="javascript:playVideo()">Play</a>
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't in Internet Explorer (I've tested in IE11).
It says

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'pauseVideo'
```

(You can see error in Developer tools).

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I posted the same thing to Google.
It works now.

I'm still not sure if it was my computer or they did something.